# Covnerting PDF's to TBitmap image

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

what is the easiest method to convert a PDF into a TBitmap image in delphi?
if there are any commercial available tools for delphi, I can buy one if it is reliable and or not expensive...

I am thinking of some kind of viewer which I can browse pages.. zoom... and export in the desired resolution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had good results with [QuickPDF](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/index.php).  It's relatively inexpensive and there is a trial version available.

Comment: ok, any more suggestions, before I close this :) is it possible to use Adobe's own ActiveX component for something like this also ?

i am thinking about more or less grabbing a 1:1 proportionally close to the resolution 1016x648 300 DPI..

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the ghostscript api from delphi (see http://ftp.uasw.edu/pub/ghostscript/contrib/ for delphi example files) to convert to a bitmap.

Though I've not used it (was just aware of its existence) I would expect you should be able to put the data into a memory stream and read it from there.

Though, if your software is going to be non-open source it could be an issue .